# how to run a batch file and read output

Tags: c++, winapi

This code is supposed to run a batch file and return its output.  I verified the batch file is running but the output is not read.  It exits with a broken pipe error.

```
vector<string> getDrawingNames(const string &projectName) {
    logFile << "starting getDrawingNames" <<endl;
    vector<string> drwNames;
    HANDLE hOutputRead, hOutputWrite, hErrorWrite;
    HANDLE hInputWrite, hInputRead;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    logFile << "creating pipes" << endl;
    ::CreatePipe(&hOutputRead, &hOutputWrite, &sa, 0);
    ::CreatePipe(&hInputRead, &hInputWrite, &sa, 0);
    ::DuplicateHandle(::GetCurrentProcess(), hOutputWrite, ::GetCurrentProcess(), &hErrorWrite, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

    ::SetHandleInformation(hOutputRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
    ::SetHandleInformation(hInputWrite, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    logFile << "setting startup info" << endl;
    STARTUPINFOA startWinInfo;
    memset(&startWinInfo, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFOA));
    startWinInfo.cb = sizeof(startWinInfo);
    startWinInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    startWinInfo.hStdOutput = hOutputWrite;
    startWinInfo.hStdInput = hInputRead;
    startWinInfo.hStdError = hErrorWrite;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION procHandles;

    char * cmdname = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    char * cmdargs = "/C \"C:\\Users\\Greg\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\DimExtractor\\getDrawingNames.bat\"";  
    DWORD    procFlags;
    DWORD    waitStatus = 0;
    DWORD    procStatus = 0;
    DWORD    winErrCode;
    DWORD    inloop = 1;

    procFlags = (CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP);

    procHandles.hProcess = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    procHandles.hThread = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    procHandles.dwProcessId = 0;
    procHandles.dwThreadId = 0;

    logFile << "about to CreateProcessA..." << endl;
    BOOL result = CreateProcessA(cmdname, cmdargs, NULL, NULL, 0, procFlags, NULL, NULL, &startWinInfo, &procHandles);  
    if (result == 0)
    {
        logFile << "problem with CreateProcessA, error=" << GetLastError() << endl;
        ::CloseHandle(hOutputWrite);
        ::CloseHandle(hInputRead);
        ::CloseHandle(hErrorWrite);
        ::CloseHandle(hOutputRead);
        ::CloseHandle(hInputWrite);

        return drwNames;
    }

    logFile << "closing handles..." << endl;
    ::CloseHandle(procHandles.hThread); // we don't need it

    // close handles we passed -> now the process is responsible for closing them
    ::CloseHandle(hOutputWrite);
    ::CloseHandle(hInputRead);
    ::CloseHandle(hErrorWrite);

    // read pipe until the process terminates
    int iResult = 0;
    char strBuffer[256];
    DWORD rd;

    logFile << "reading output..." << endl;
    while (true)
    {
        logFile << "about to ReadFile..." << endl;
        if (!ReadFile(hOutputRead, strBuffer, 256, &rd, NULL))
        {
            logFile << "problem with ReadFile, error=" << GetLastError() << endl;
            if (::GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE) {
                logFile << "error was a broken pipe" << endl;
                break; // terminated
            }
            else
            {
                logFile << "error was something other than a broke pipe" << endl;
                iResult = -1;
                break;
            }
        }

        INT iTest = IS_TEXT_UNICODE_CONTROLS;

        if (::IsTextUnicode(strBuffer, rd, &iTest)) {
            logFile << strBuffer;
            wprintf((wchar_t *)strBuffer);
        }
        else {
            logFile << strBuffer;
            printf((char *)strBuffer);
        }
    }

    logFile << "closing handles2" << endl;
    ::CloseHandle(procHandles.hProcess);
    ::CloseHandle(hOutputRead);
    ::CloseHandle(hInputWrite);
    logFile << "returning" << endl;

    return drwNames;
}
```

Ignore the return values for now. I'm just trying to verify the output from the batch file is being read.  It exits with a broken pipe error.  I don't get why.

Here is the output of the batch file if I run it manually:

```
C:\Users\Greg\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DimExtractor>getDrawingNames.bat
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    85  100    30  100    55     30     55  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   319
Our auth: "-48438904427905703"
Drawing Names for Project P314_557_001 =>[{"NAME":"314.557.001"}]

Logout=>{"auth": null}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your batch file path has spaces in it so you need to surround it with quotes.

Comment: Ah, good observation.  I added the quotes and now the batch file did run and the file was created.  But it still exited with a broken pipe error while trying to read the output.

Comment: You need cmd /c to execute a batch file.

Comment: Its in there:     char * cmdargs = "/C \"C:\\Users\\Greg\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\DimExtractor\\getDrawingNames.bat\"";

Comment: At a guess I'd say the process you launched has exited (and closed its handle on the pipe) before you start trying to read from it. Since you've closed your own handle as well the pipe is dead.

Comment: @JonathanPotter He still has the read end of the output pipe `hOutputRead`. I think that the child process's call to `WriteFile(stdout)` waits until the output is read by the parent process, so the child process shouldn't be able to finish before the parent had a chance to read the output.

Comment: I tried commenting out all the CloseHandle statements before the read.  This time it did not exit with a broken pipe but it entered the endless loop and hung the app.  Nothing ever output to the logFile after "about to ReadFile..."

Comment: for what you create 5 different pipe handles when 2 is enough ? create one pipe pair - server for self process and client for cmd - assign this handle for hStdInput, hStdOutput, hStdError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error in call `CreateProcessA` - you use `bInheritHandles = 0`. as result any your pipe handles not inherited by cmd. it write to invisible console and exit.

you from self side after call `::CloseHandle(hOutputWrite);` broke the `hOutputRead` - the server pipe end was broken, after **last** connected to it client pipe end is closed. if `hOutputWrite` will be inherited by cmd - your `hOutputRead` will broken only after both - you and cm close `hOutputWrite`. but because cmd not got it - it broken just after your close own copy. and on `ReadFile` you just got `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`

if you not call `::CloseHandle(hOutputWrite);` - of course `hOutputRead` will be not broken, but `ReadFile(hOutputRead..)` never return because nobody write to `hOutputWrite`.

so if you change to `bInheritHandles = true` in call `CreateProcess` your code faster of all begin work as excepted.

---

however some note:

call `::DuplicateHandle(::GetCurrentProcess(), hOutputWrite, ::GetCurrentProcess(), &hErrorWrite, 0, TRUE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)` - absolute senseless - you can do `hErrorWrite = hOutputWrite` with the same effect. duplicate handle not create new object - it only create new handle (pointer) to the same object. for what have 2 handles for the **same** pipe end in this case ? in your case `hStdError` and `hStdOutput` will be different handles to the same file object. even serialization for synchronous file object was per file object, but not per handle. exist sense have different pipes for `hStdError` and `hStdOutput` if we want separate process error and normal output. but no sense have different handles to the **same** file.

you create 5 (!) different pipe handles. really enough have 2 pipe handles: in case asynchronous pipes or in your concrete case when one side only write and another side only read. both with `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX`. not need separate handles for `hStdInput` and `StdOutput` - the same handle for both (with `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX` and read/write access) just fine.

use different handles for read and write can be need only in case synchronous pipes. because all synchronous operation is serialized - new 
operation not begin until previous is end. this can cause deadlock (even if another side use asynchronous handles). for example side, which used synchronous io first call read and than in separate thread call write (on the same handle). but write not begin execute (will be blocked in io manager, until previous read not finished). if another side first wait on some data, before call write - it never got this data (write on another side begin after read finished, which finished only after we write something to pipe). if we use asynchronous pipes - read/write not serialized - can execute in concurrent. as result never be deadlock. also in most case will be enough have asynchronous parent with synchronous child like *cmd* (which yourself serialize read/write operation). and your code anyway nothing write to pipes - so assume that another side nothing read, but only write. in this case also will be no deadlock even with full synchronous (from both side) pipe pair.

also `CreatePipe` is very bad designed api - not let create such pipe pair (read/write, full duplex). need use `CreateNamedPipeW` + `CreateFileW` instead. (*begin from win7 possible create un-named pipe pair, but for this need use `ZwCreateNamedPipeFile`, `CreateNamedPipeW` - can not do this*)

worked code example

```
ULONG CreatePipeAnonymousPair(PHANDLE phServerPipe, PHANDLE phClientPipe)
{
    static LONG s;
    if (!s)
    {
        ULONG seed = GetTickCount();
        InterlockedCompareExchange(&s, RtlRandomEx(&seed), 0);
    }

    WCHAR name[64];

    swprintf(name, L"\\\\.\\Pipe\\Win32Pipes.%08x.%08x", GetCurrentProcessId(), InterlockedIncrement(&s));

    HANDLE hServerPipe = CreateNamedPipeW(name, 
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX|FILE_READ_DATA|FILE_WRITE_DATA, 
        PIPE_TYPE_BYTE|PIPE_READMODE_BYTE, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (hServerPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        static SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), 0, TRUE };

        HANDLE hClientPipe = CreateFileW(name, FILE_GENERIC_READ|FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

        if (hClientPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            *phServerPipe = hServerPipe, *phClientPipe = hClientPipe;

            return NOERROR;
        }

        CloseHandle(hServerPipe);
    }

    return GetLastError();
}

void PrintOem(PSTR buf, ULONG cb)
{
    if (int cchWideChar = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP, 0, buf, cb, 0, 0))
    {
        PWSTR wz = (PWSTR)alloca(cchWideChar * sizeof(WCHAR));

        if (MultiByteToWideChar(CP_OEMCP, 0, buf, cb, wz, cchWideChar))
        {
            if (ULONG cbMultiByte = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wz, cchWideChar, 0, 0, 0, 0))
            {
                PSTR sz = (PSTR)alloca(cbMultiByte);

                if (WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, wz, cchWideChar, sz, cbMultiByte, 0, 0))
                {
                    DbgPrint("%.*s", cbMultiByte, sz);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ULONG ExecCmd(PWSTR cmdline, PCWSTR CurrentDirectory)
{
    WCHAR ApplicationName[MAX_PATH];
    if (!GetEnvironmentVariableW(L"ComSpec", ApplicationName, RTL_NUMBER_OF(ApplicationName)))
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    STARTUPINFOEXW si = { { sizeof(si) } };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    HANDLE hPipe;
    ULONG err = CreatePipeAnonymousPair(&hPipe, &si.StartupInfo.hStdError);

    if (!err)
    {
        si.StartupInfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        si.StartupInfo.hStdInput = si.StartupInfo.hStdOutput = si.StartupInfo.hStdError;

        ULONG dwCreationFlags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW;
        //++ optional
        BOOL fInit = FALSE;
        SIZE_T Size;
        if (!InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(0, 1, 0, &Size) &&
            GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER &&
            InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList = (LPPROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST)alloca(Size), 1, 0, &Size))
        {
            fInit = TRUE;
            if (UpdateProcThreadAttribute(si.lpAttributeList, 0, PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST, 
                &si.StartupInfo.hStdError, sizeof(HANDLE), 0, 0))
            {
                dwCreationFlags |= EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT;
            }
        }
        //-- optional

        if (CreateProcessW(ApplicationName, cmdline, 0, 0, TRUE, dwCreationFlags, 0, 
            CurrentDirectory, &si.StartupInfo, &pi))
        {
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        }
        else
        {
            err = GetLastError();
        }

        if (fInit)
        {
            DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(si.lpAttributeList);
        }

        CloseHandle(si.StartupInfo.hStdError);

        if (!err)
        {
            CHAR buf[0x1000], *sz;
            ULONG dwBytes, cb;

            while (ReadFile(hPipe, buf, sizeof(buf), &dwBytes, 0) && dwBytes)
            {
                sz = buf;

                do 
                {
                    PrintOem(sz, cb = min(dwBytes, 256));

                } while (sz += cb, dwBytes -= cb);
            }
        }

        CloseHandle(hPipe);
    }

    return err;
}
```

the `cmdline` usually like `"/c some.bat"` or `"/c \"so me.bat\""`. path to bat we can set in cmdline (use full path) or set it in `CurrentDirectory`

Comment: Q2hlY2sgeW91ciBza3lwZS4uLg==

Comment: RbMm-Thank you for taking the time to write up a reply.  Unfortunately, I'm not experienced enough in C++ to understand it.  It seems very simple what I want to do.  Run a batch file and read the result.  Yet, I could find no good examples on google.  I'm going to have to give up on this approach.  Didn't really like it anyway because it requires the client computer to have curl installed.  I saw some examples of curl modules in C++ so I'm going to pursue that route instead.

Comment: @user3217883 - how curl here related ? you can change 1 symbol in self code `CreateProcessA(cmdname, cmdargs, NULL, NULL, 1, procFlags, NULL, NULL, &startWinInfo, &procHandles);` (0 -> 1) for it begin work. than remove `DuplicateHandle` and `hErrorWrite` at all and set `startWinInfo.hStdError = hOutputWrite`. how your code will be work after this minimal changes ? about move from 4 pipes to 2 - this already optional.

Comment: Ok, I changed 0 to 1 and ran again.  This time I got an extra ReadFile in the output. Log file now shows "about to ReadFile..." then another "about to ReadFile..."  I'll try your other suggestions and comment again.  By the way, curl is used in the batch file to connect to another server and download some things.  It would be better to have curl embedded in the C++ so the client would not need to install it on their computer.

Comment: Hey its working now somewhat!  I commented out the DuplicateHandle and anything that had hErrorWrite and ran again.  This time I got back results.  This time there were 8 "about to ReadFile..." lines followed by data.  After the 8 there was "problem with ReadFile, error=109; error was a broken pipe; closing handles2; returning"  So I guess it doesn't exit gracefully after it reaches the end but this is progress!  I will give you credit for the answer.  Thanks RbMm!

Comment: @user3217883 - *error=109; error was a broken pipe;* - you and must got this error when child process close it handle. *So I guess it doesn't exit gracefully after* - no, you mistake. all was absolute ok. the error 109 - always **must be**.